# Codeigniter - Search profile using username entered in URL

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url, tankauth, codeigniter-routing

I am using Codeigniter and Tank Auth and I am using Ubuntu OS. When I access my project using my IP, it comes something like:

```
http://192.168.1.10/project/auth/login
```

I have to implement a functionality of searching a profile using URL. Suppose if I enter

```
http://192.168.1.10/project/vishmay
```

Then it should show my profile. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

I have tried doing this in my routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['auth/login'] = 'auth/login';
$route['auth/register'] = 'auth/register';
$route['auth/logout'] = 'auth/logout';
$route['welcome/profile'] = 'welcome/profile';
$route[':any'] = 'auth/index/$1';
```

and also made index() in auth.php controller like

```
 function index() {
        $username=$this->uri->segment(1);
        $data['result']=$this->users->get_profile_pic1($username);   
        if ($message = $this->session->flashdata('message')) {
            $data['reg_success'] = "You have been registered successfully.";
            $reg_success = 1;
            redirect('/auth/register', $data);
        } else {
            redirect('/auth/login/');
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you getting user name by this $this->uri->segment(1);

Comment: no, I have echoed it, but it is not printing username, and when I enter URL like  `http://192.168.1.10/project/vishmay`. It displays a completely blank page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change:

```
$route[':any'] = 'auth/index/$1';
```

to

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'auth/index/$1';
```

to make the `$1` can correctly get the segment value.

And you can try this code:

Try this:

```
function index($username = '') {
    $data['result']=$this->users->get_profile_pic1($username);   
    if ($message = $this->session->flashdata('message')) {
        $data['reg_success'] = "You have been registered successfully.";
        $reg_success = 1;
        redirect('/auth/register', $data);
    } else {
        redirect('/auth/login/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Still the same result, it is not even going inside the model.

Comment: @VishmayPatel Were you trying `$username=$this->uri->segment(1);` or the function I posted just before?

Comment: I am using the function that you posted.

Comment: It worked, I just forgot to comment one of the `exit;` that I usually use for debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking for it since yesterday.